# Adding an affiliation to an accepted paper

Tags: publications, publishers

I am the corresponding and the first author of a paper which has been accepted for publication in a journal published by Springer.

I have an important question that is I would like to know whether I can add another university as my second affiliation (before, I only use one affiliation for me) and what should I do to make this addition.

Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can make this change. The easiest way to do it is to wait for the journal office to send you the proofs. If you're worried this might be too late, you can also contact the journal office directly.

Don't email the editorial board because their role is over (they handle peer review, and this is not a peer review issue).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have sent an email to the publishing editor of the journal.

Answer (score 1):

Email the editor using the journal submission site (there should be some method to send adhoc questions) and ask, explaining your issue. If you have changed jobs, for example, it is usual to use the current affiliation on the publication with some sort of note that the work was completed while working at the other institution.

Do not contact the editor through other channels - this is a publishing issue and should be dealt with through the publisher's tools.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your comment. I have sent an email to the publishing editor.

Answer (score 1):

> can [I] add another university as my second affiliation...what should I do to make this addition

Assuming your manuscript has been *accepted for publication*, but you haven't yet submitted a camera-ready manuscript, then just add a second affiliation. If you're concerned that this might not be permitted, then read the journal's rules.